# UITextField AutoFill not filling when text fields are embedded in storyboard

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, autofill

Here is the layout that I use:

[image: Storyboard]

When I use AutoFill feature, it fills only the focused text field, for example the first one:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

In the simple layout when all the fields are placed in the same view controller everything works fine. `textContentType` is set correctly to `.username` and `.password`.

I tested this on both device and simulator with the same results.

Full example on GitHub: https://github.com/silvansky/AutoFillTest

What should I do to tell iOS these fields are related to each other and should be filled together even if they are from different view controllers?

Comment: It's likely you cannot (easily) do this... the text fields are in separate controllers, so iOS would have no reason to associate them with each other. Is there a particular reason you're trying to do it this way?

Comment: This is simplified example, in real project my text field lives in a separate storyboard and it's reused in several screens: sign in, sign up, restore password, change account. So it's very easy to keep it like this. But looks like I have to get rid of view controller for the text field and move all the logic to view.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same feature, you are talking about. For the purpose of easiness and reusability of text fields in multiple screens. You can make a .xib files along with its class for the textfield and password field. After that apply that class to the main fields class and set is textContentType to .password or user name. It will work fine. In my app, I am using textfields in multiples screen and I have achieved it using described way.

Comment: The problem was that text fields were in different storyboards and each had it's own view controller. So only the focused one auto filled. I changed storyboard to xib and got rid of the view controller, now everything works.

Comment: Great. That is where I felt your problem is. That is why I suggested you to use Xib files instead of view controller for text field.